# Error link to another page with href (Error with %E2%80%8B code in my localhost url)

Tags: codeigniter, href

I tried to make a button that linked to another page. But it seems so weird because it shows an error when the button was clicked.

> The requested URL /â€‹index.php/fin/bukti_kas/add_dokkas was not found on this server.

And when I tried to copy the URL from the browser it gave me this strange URL:

> http://localhost/%E2%80%8Bindex.php/fin/bukti_kas/add_dokkas

There is %E2%80%8B, and that what makes the link not work.

My controller (add_dokkas.php):

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->model_dokkas->logged_id())
    {
        $data_pribadi['test'] = array(
            $usrid       = $this->session->userdata('USRID'),
            $employee_id = $this->session->userdata('EMPLOYEE_ID'),
            $passwd      = $this->session->userdata('PASSWD'),
            $ket_jbt     = $this->session->userdata('KET_JBT'),
            $ket_gas     = $this->session->userdata('KET_GAS')
        );
        $this->load->view('fin/bukti_kas/v_add_dokkas', $data_pribadi);      
    }else{
        redirect("fin/bukti_kas/login");
    }
}
```

And my view (v_add_dokkas.php):

```
<div class="container py-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center mb-2">Pembuatan Dokumen Bukti Kas/Bank(NEW)</h2>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px">
                <div class="" style="padding:10px; margin: 0px">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url();?>​index.php/fin/bukti_kas/add_dokkas" role="button">Link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="grid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My config base :

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Why do I get this error/strange URL?

Comment: did you try to make the link relative? like: `<a  href="/fin/bukti_kas/add_dokkas"` with a route `$route['fin/bukti_kas/add_dokkas']="bukti_kas/add_dokkas"`

Comment: not yet sir, but I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been solving my problem with this:

```
<?php echo anchor(site_url('index.php/fin/bukti_kas/dokkas/add_dokkas'), 'Create', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?>
```